# How to filter spaces from a redirected link in Java?

Tags: java

I've been stuck on a problem for quite a while now. I have the following code:

```
String fileUrl = "example.com/some_redirect_page_to_a_download_page.html";
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
```

What this does is trying to fetch the response code when trying to connect to an URL. For most download links I input, it returns response code 200, which is what I want. However, for some of the download links it returns 505. I've been searching the internet for the problem here, and I found that the answer was: there are spaces in the link. The problem is, is that all links I use are first redirections before I get to fetch the file from the final link. HttpURLConnection automatically follows all of these redirections, but stupidly keeps the spaces in the final link, on which I get the error code 505. Also, there doesn't seem to be any field in HttpURLConnection from which I can fetch this final link in order to remove the spaces from it myself.

Example:

```
String fileUrl = "http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/hillside-manor/download/schematic/";
URL url = new URL(fileURL);
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
httpConn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.76"); 
int responseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
return responseCode;
```

This returns the following error:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 505 for URL: http://static.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/schematic/Hillside Manor v10.schematic
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1840)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
at PMCParser.getFinalURL(PMCParser.java:47)
at PMCParser.getFinalURL(PMCParser.java:51)
at PMCParser.getFileSize(PMCParser.java:136)
at PMCParser.seekByTitle(PMCParser.java:76)
at PMCParser.run(PMCParser.java:37)
```

Does anyone have any clue on how to solve this?

Comment: Maybe: http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E505.html

Comment: @RC. Thanks for trying to help out. I know how to fix the 505 error, I just don't have the thing I need (the actual URL I'm trying to connect to) to fix the issue...

Comment: Try a replace(" ", ""); on the URL, that way it will first replace the spaces with nothing or replace(" ", "+"); if you need the space in url format.

Comment: @Leo Thanks for trying to help out. I know how to filter the spaces in the link, if I at least had the link. Do you know how to get the final link after those redirects?

Comment: What about catching the 505 and then getting the URL, replace the spaces and try again?

Comment: There's a class called HttpServletRequest. You can get the URL as a String or the URI as a StringBuffer from it, not sure if this is what you need =).

Comment: Also, the HttpUrlConnection class has a .getURL property, try using it

Comment: @Leo Sadly the getURL always returns the url before redirections

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tested myself, I suggest you to disable the automatic redirect following:

```
HttpURLConnection.setFollowRedirects(false);
```

... so that you can intercept any 3xx return code and then read the URL returned in the `Location` header, and encode it properly through `URLEncoder.encode`.

(I just hope you have got no SecurityManager which prevents you to invoke `setFollowRedirects`).